# Characters appear out of the screen in the TextView!

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

Hey, I've been trying to fix this problem for a long time, The problem 
is that some characters in the text are out of the screen, here is a 
screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:background="@drawable/list" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="15dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <TextView 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000" 
        android:id="@+id/Munawwat_Text_TextView_text" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest a way/workaround to fix this problem?
A workaround for this is to put it into an EditText. If I put the text 
into the EditText, the EditText gets horizontally scrollable 
(scrollable for ~3px) which is good so you can see the characters that 
are out of the screen but i dont want to let the users mess with the 
text.. So:

1. Is it possible to not allow the users to edit in the EditText and 
   in the same time let the EditText get scrollable?
2. Is there any other view that i can put the TextView into it, so it 
   can get scrollable a bit so I can see the characters? (limit the 
   scroll of the view)
3. Is there a way to limit the number of characters in each line in 
   the TextView?

I know I asked a lot though this is one of the last problem I have so 
I would really appreciate any comment/suggestion! 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding the TextView inside a ScollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your TextView in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).  Or make the text smaller.  Or try adding [padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) on the left to see if it forces linebreaks.

Comment: Padding and making the text smaller doesnt work, same result.. About the ScrollView, can I make the scrollview horizontally scrollable by just ~5 pixels?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, sorry; none of my tests work.  Another approach might be to use the EditText, and then use a key listener to catch and consume all keypresses?

Answer (score 0):

and try to use weight :D
it limites number of caracteres in textview

```
android:maxLength
```

Comment: That will shorten the lines but also have other characters out of the screen :(